# Why do I see files from another GCP Kubernetes cluster in a different cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to learn Google Cloud and very new to it.

I created 1 project in GCP: **project1**.

And I created a Kubernetes cluster in project1 with the name **p1-cluster1**. In this cluster, I click on the **Connect** button and a terminal is opened on GCP page. I created a new directory with the name **development** under **/home/me**. And I have developed a personal project under **/home/me/development** so that I now have a bunch of code here.

I decided to develop a second personal project. For this purpose, I created a new project with the name **project2** in GCP. And then created a new Kubernetes cluster with the name **p2-cluster2**. And when I connect to this cluster, a terminal window opens, and I automatically end up in my home folder **/home/me**. I expect to see an empty folder but I instead see the **development** folder that I created in **project1** in **p1-cluster1**.

Why do I see contents/files of another project (and another cluster) in a different project (and cluster)? Am I doing something wrong? If this is normal, what is the benefit of creating different projects?

I can create a new folder with the name **development_2**. But what if I accidentally ruin things (i.e. operative system) when working under **development** folder..? Do I also ruin things for the project under the **development_2** folder?

And also, if I simultaneously run 2 tasks in 2 different projects, will they be competing with each other for the system resources (i.e. memory and CPU)?

This is extremely confusing and I could not make it clear to me by looking at documentation. I would really appreciate help of more experienced people in this specific domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you use Cloud shell to "connect" to the clusters. This is just a convenient way instead of using your own machine's shell. You get a machine which can be used for development instead of your local machine.

Therefore you have the same files and the some directory. It is not on the GKE Cluster, but a "local" machine from the perspective of GKE.

In order to actually execute something on the cluster you have to use `kubectl` which has a concept of kube contexts. If you have multiple clusters, then you need multiple kube contexts.

So if you "Connect" that from p1-cluster1 your kube-context will be set to that cluster.

See these articles for more detail:

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/quickstart#launch

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-access-for-kubectl

EDIT:

So when you do

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials p1-cluster1
```

on your local machine, you can the context to call

```
kubectl get pods
```

on that cluster. Only that command is executed on the cluster.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Reading these articles, I am unfortunately not able to figure out answers to my questions. Am I interpreting your explanation correctly that even my first project under the /home/me/development directory is actually not connected to my p1-cluster1 cluster? As usual, I am always disappointed with documentation of Google products. :( The documentation explains things as if I will deploy a Web server, which is not my intention at all and the docs do not cover my usecase.

Comment: Just think that this Cloud Shell is like your local machine. But remember, Kubernetes is complex system which might be daunting at first. 
If you are not familiar with Kubernetes, you might try getting some experience with that before working with multiple clusters